# What is the percentage increase to any value when initial value is 0?

Tags: percentages

This is a very simple maths problem, which doesn’t seems simple to me when I just put some extra thoughts on it. So need to borrow some extra brains for this.

Question:
If cost of coffee in my office was Dollar 0 till yesterday and today it is Dollar 2.5 then what is the percentage increase in the cost of coffee?

Initially it seemed like 2.5% increase, simply
by distributing number from 0 to 100, but this is not the case.

Some suggested it is *infinitely* more than the previous value, because we are calculating percentage by dividing by zero. But what about this if the cost of coffee was $0.25? Isn’t still *infinitely* more! Something is wrong here.

PS:
Yes, coffee were free in our office but not anymore, and we are still recovering from this shocker.

Comment: "Isn’t still infinitely more!": no.

Comment: Bring your own coffee machine and sell coffee for $1.50. This will teach office management!

Comment: you can say that, in the old days, it costed $100 %$ less !

Answer (score 5):

The relative increase from $a$ to $b$, which is given wrt $a$, is computed in percent as

$$100\,\frac{b-a}a.$$

Hence,

- $0$ to $2.5\to100\,\dfrac{2.5-0}{0}=\infty\%$,
- $0.25$ to $2.5\to100\,\dfrac{2.5-0.25}{0.25}=900\%$.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say the initial cost of coffee in your office was $\$0$ per cup. Now a cup of coffee costs $\$2.5$. We could use the following formula to try to come up with the answer for the increase in the price of coffee in terms of percents:

$$
\text{cost_now}=\text{initial_cost}+\frac{\text{initial_cost}}{100}\cdot\text{percentage_change}.
$$

$$$2.5=$0+\frac{$0}{100}\cdot p\implies 0\cdot p=2.5.$$

There is no real number such that when you multiply it by zero, it gives you a nonzero quantity. I guess, one possible interpretation of this result would be that with the initial cost of $\$0$, the concept of increase/decrease in percentage does not really apply. In other words, when you're talking about the increase/decrease in the cost of something percentage-wise, you necessarily need an initial cost that's greater than zero as the basis for your calculations. If there is no initial cost, there can be no calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: percent change is undefined when the starting quantity is $0$. Calling it a $2.5\%$ increase makes no more sense than calling it a $\frac{\pi^2}{\sqrt{17}}\%$ increase (why would you distribute anything on a $(0,100)$ interval?)

If you want a bit of an intuition, imagine it raised from $\$1$ to $\$1.10$. Take the starting prize, increase it by $5\%$. You are still below the current prize. Go back and increse again, this time by $6\%$ instead. You are still below. When you get to $10\%$, you stop being below the current prize.

Now start at $0$. Increase $0$ by 10%. You are below the current prize. Now try $20\%$, $50\%$, $1,000,000\%$. You still haven't reached the current prize, and you never will. Therefore if makes sense to talk about an "infinitely big percentage increase"

Comment: price, not prize

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{margin}=1-({1\over {1+\text{markup}}}) $$ Or equivalently,$$\text{markup}= ({1\over {1-\text{margin}}})-1$$ where markup and margin are written in decimal form (0.25=25% etc.). If we have 100% margin (1 in decimal), then we hit a division by 0 error.  It's undefined if the margin comes from simply setting a price after having it at 0.