# Percentual increase when the old Value is zero

Tags: percentages

How do I compute the increase when the old value is zero? I know that usually we compute it as
$$
\frac{N-V}{V} \times 100,
$$
where $N$ is the new value and $V$ is the old value.

So,

- going from $50$ to $500$, the increase is $900\% = \frac{500-50}{50} \times 100$
- going from $50$ to $75$, the increase is $50\% = \frac{100-50}{50} \times 100$

But when going zero to $X$, where $X$ is any value greater than zero, the increase is $100\%$? (In this formula you can't divide by zero).

Comment: The percentage change you seek is undefined/"infinity" no matter what the new value is.  It's not a meaningful answer to "By how much did this increase from zero?"  The only meaningful answer to that question is to count how many new ____ you got after you started counting from 0.

Comment: thanks @gt6989b for formatting in LaTeX and for better description. Cheers.

Comment: @nomen, I'm implementing a financial system, the customer initial income is zero, then when the customer have for example 1000 dollars, what value of increase I should put in percentual? 0 to 1000 is an increase?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the percentage increase to any value when initial value is 0?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3288982/what-is-the-percentage-increase-to-any-value-when-initial-value-is-0)

Comment: @an4s, it's the same question but the answer for this problem didn't have a single answer, matematically the answer is that the increase is undetermined number. I will have to create some artifice to treat that exception.

Comment: @Lucas: don't make the initial balance 0.  Make the initial balance whatever the customer deposits. :-)

Comment: Interesting thing: inverting the variables, the result is always -100%.

500 to 0 is -100%

300 to 0 is -100%

X to 0 is -100%, where x > 0